# Warning in useEffect even with correct formatting

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have the following useEffect in my component:

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            if (!user.id) {
                const userData = await getData()
                if (userData.id) {
                    dispatch(addShops(userData.filterShops))
                    dispatch(login({ name: userData.name, id: userData.id }))
                } else {
                    setStart(false)
                }
            } else {
                setStart(false)
            }
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [user])
```

I declared an asynchronous function inside the useEffect and executed it right after, as recommended by the documentation.However, I still get the alert:

> Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which
> is used for clean-up. It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () =>
> ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside
> your effect and call it immediately

Is there something wrong with my code to display this alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in another useEffect, where I forgot to put the {}. With that the arrow function was returning the asynchronous function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Wrong:
`useEffect(() => fetchData(), [user])`

Corret:
`useEffect(() => { fetchData() }, [user])`

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you, fetchData() is returning a promise, which is not allowed. You should return your fetched data to a then()-statement and process it further from there:

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            if (!user.id) {
                const userData = await getData();
                return userData;
            } else {
                return {};
            }
        }

        fetchData()
            .then((userData) => {
                if(userData.id) {
                    dispatch(addShops(userData.filterShops));
                    dispatch(login({ name: userData.name, id: userData.id }));
                } else {
                    setStart(false);
                }
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                // handle your errors here
            }
    }, [user]);
```

Comment: Hi @Conrad Neumann, as suggested I applied a then()-statement, but but the warning remains. If you look at the alert, it does not ask to apply a then()-statement:

**It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately:

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state**

Comment: Ok, in that case, please provide more of your code. A reproducable example would be great.

Comment: https://github.com/bedsistemas/useeffect_warning.git

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I looked into the code but everything seems to work fine (besides some Linter warnings). Since the dispatch-functions are not part of the code you provided, I can only assume, that the problem is somewhere in this part. Please look further into your dispatches. A wild guess would be, to `await` the dispatchers. I've seen people doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip my friend, but the example I shared is giving the same alert, and it does not have the dispatch functions. If in your case you didn't receive the warning, it could be some difference in the environment (RN version for example). In the repo I put in README.md information about my environment, can you reproduce?

Comment: Sorry, you are right: I unconsciously changed this line: `useEffect(() => fetchData(), [user])` to this `useEffect(() => {fetchData()}, [user])`to solve a Linter error. That way, `fetchData()` doesn't implicitly return anything and negates the type error regarding `returning Promise<void | Destructor>`. Besides that I changed nothing.

Comment: Exactly, I forget the {} in the example, with them the warning disappeared. But in my app it keeps appearing, I'll try to follow your dispatch tip and let you know about the news.

Comment: My fried, I find... It was in another component, I forgot to put the {} in it, like in the GitHug repo example, solved. Thanks